# How Can I Make a Flight Single Trip Request

Tags: air, sabre

I have the following Request to Round Trip Flights and I want to make a single trip request with the same data except the return date...!
Any one can help with this?

```
https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2018-01-05&returndate=2018-01-05&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=Y&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US
```

Then the headers are:

```
Authorization: Bearer

X-Originating-Ip:
```

After removing the return date as follows:

```
https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2018-01-05&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=Y&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US
```

And after I put the same headers to the request, I received an error:

What I need is to convert that request to single trip request.
Anyone can help with this?

Comment: What error are you getting? You might be getting a "No results were found" since not many one-way trips are loaded for this API

Comment: Yes,  this exactly what I got.